# How do i load XML using TinyXML into Console application

Tags: c++, xml

I'm simply just trying to load an XML document into my C++ Console application using TinyXml2. However I keep getting errors which I'm not sure how to resolve. I'm new to c++ and I've attempted to follow the examples to the best of my knowledge. Why do i get these errors when attempting to load and xml? I've hard coding the path directly to the xml file.

I installed TinyXML2 and included into my project using the NuGetPackage manager.
Here is my code..

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "tinyxml2.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace tinyxml2;
using namespace std;


void LoadGraph(const char* xmlFilepath)
{
    XMLDocument doc;
    doc.LoadFile(xmlFilepath);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Loading file\n";
    LoadGraph("C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/graphTestings/testGraph.xml");

    return 0;
}
```

The errors I keep getting are...

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  LNK1120 3 unresolved
> externals ExampleConsoleApp   E:\Users\Martini\Projects\XML_Parsing\ExampleConsoleApp\Debug\ExampleConsoleApp.exe 1
>
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
> tinyxml2::XMLDocument::XMLDocument(bool,enum tinyxml2::Whitespace)"
> (??0XMLDocument@tinyxml2@@QAE@_NW4Whitespace@1@@Z) referenced in
> function "void __cdecl LoadGraph(char const *)"
> (?LoadGraph@@YAXPBD@Z)    ExampleConsoleApp   E:\Users\Martini\Projects\XML_Parsing\ExampleConsoleApp\ExampleConsoleApp\ExampleConsoleApp.obj 1
>
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall
> tinyxml2::XMLDocument::~XMLDocument(void)"
> (??1XMLDocument@tinyxml2@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl
> LoadGraph(char const *)"
> (?LoadGraph@@YAXPBD@Z)    ExampleConsoleApp   E:\Users\Martini\Projects\XML_Parsing\ExampleConsoleApp\ExampleConsoleApp\ExampleConsoleApp.obj 1
>
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: enum
> tinyxml2::XMLError __thiscall tinyxml2::XMLDocument::LoadFile(char
> const *)" (?LoadFile@XMLDocument@tinyxml2@@QAE?AW4XMLError@2@PBD@Z)
> referenced in function "void __cdecl LoadGraph(char const *)"
> (?LoadGraph@@YAXPBD@Z)    ExampleConsoleApp   E:\Users\Martini\Projects\XML_Parsing\ExampleConsoleApp\ExampleConsoleApp\ExampleConsoleApp.obj 1

Comment: You need to link against TinyXML. Find the relevant .lib file and place the DLL next to the executable

Comment: Doesn't nuget do that? Is it the same as adding the referecent?

Comment: I doubt it, it's not C#. Check the linker flags

Comment: Alroght I'll double check. This is my first c++ project so I appreciate the help. I'm more of a heavy c# developer.

Answer (score -2):

Worked for me: Menu->Project->"Add to project"  choose tinyxml2.cpp and tinyxml2.h